# How do I merge two data frames in Python Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames df1 and df2 and I would like to merge them into a single data frame. It is as if df1 and df2 were created by splitting a single data frame down the center vertically, like tearing a piece of paper that contains a list in half so that half the columns go on one paper and half the columns go on the other. I would like to merge them back together. How do I do it?

Answer (score 7):

Pandas has a built-in merge function. Please refer to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
End-result should be something like this:
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['name_indexcolumn_df1_here'],
              right_on=['name_indexcolumn_df2_here'],
              how='inner')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you split the DataFrame "vertically" then you have two DataFrames that with the same index.

You can use the **merge** function or the **concat** function.

With **concat** with would be something like this:

```
pandas.DataFrame.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

With **merge** with would be something like this:

```
pandas.Dataframe.merge([df1,df2], left_index=True)
```

For more complex merging options see the [Merge, join and concat pandas tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Comment: merge is wrong... have you tried running the code?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the dataframes:

**Preco2018** with size (8784, 5)

[image: DataFrame 1]

**Preco 2019** with size (8760, 5)

[image: DataFrame 2]

That have the same column names.

You can combine them using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), by simply

```
import pandas as pd

frames = [Preco2018, Preco2019]

df_merged = pd.concat(frames)
```

Which results in a DataFrame with the following size (17544, 5)

[image: DataFrame result of the combination of two dataframes]

If you want to visualize, it ends up working like this

[image: How concat works]

([Image Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/merging.html))