# Pandas: How can I merge two dataframes?

Tags: pandas

I found (*[How do I merge two data frames in Python Pandas?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/how-do-i-merge-two-data-frames-in-python-pandas)*), but do not get the expected result.

I have these two CSV files:

```
# f1.csv
num   ano
76971  1975
76969  1975
76968  1975
76966  1975
76964  1975
76963  1975
76960  1975
```

and

```
# f2.csv
num   ano   dou  url
76971  1975 p1   http://exemplo.com/page1
76968  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page10
76966  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page100
```

How do I merge these for to get the result given below?

```
# Expected result
num   ano   dou  url
76971  1975 p1   http://exemplo.com/page1
76969  1975
76968  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page10
76966  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page100
76964  1975
76963  1975
76960  1975
```

Comment: There are many example on StackOverflow

Comment: @Aditya, no how i need. And i newer...

Comment: What do you mean by *"but not assert expected result"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Down vote because this is a trivial question. See SO for numerous posts similar to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f1.merge(f2, left_on='num', right_on='num', how='outer')`

see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: very thanks! 
I finish below:
a1975.merge(b1975, left_on=['num', 'ano'], right_on=['num', 'ano'], how='outer', sort=True)

Comment: Great tutorial for this kind of question.

https://www.shanelynn.ie/merge-join-dataframes-python-pandas-index-1/