# Need help on pandas data frames filtering on a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Raw data gets generated daily
We need to get 
success rate for current month on a daily basis & 
success rate of each cell by end of that month from Jan till current month.

Raw data has following columns:

```
Column Names    example values
BackupClient    an4lsbk0304.an.ppp.com
BackupDriver    NetBackup
BackupMaster    an4lsbk0300.an.ppp.com
BackupPolicyID  an.72699
BackupPolicyName    ancfsv02a_aggr1_ancfs02n02b_L_an_vlw_atom_001
Cell    an
LastFullResult  Failure
LastFullStartTime   4-10-19 
PolicyType  NFS
Status  Active
LastFullExitCode    96
```

Each column – “Cell”
I need to find following result columns:

```
Oct Full ran, failed & not completed yet
Oct Full not ran
Oct full ran successful
Grand Total
Success rate for full ran in Oct
Success rate of full backup
Percentage of backup coverage
```

1. Oct Full ran, failed & not completed yet:
   Oct full ran, failed & not completed yet means – 
   “LastFullStartTime” – contains current month date and non-empty     &&
   “LastFullResult” – Failed                       &&
   “status code” – greater than 1
2. Oct Full not ran yet:

Oct Full not ran means –
“LastFullStartTime” - empty or date older than current month

3. Oct full ran successful –
   Oct full ran successful means –
   “LastFullStartTime” – contains current month date           &&
   “LastFullResult” – success
4. Grand Total
   Grand Total means –
   Count of BackupPolicyID for each distinct cell; should be ideally equal to above 3 columns (1+2+3=4)
5. Success rate for full ran in Oct
   Success rate for full ran in Oct means –
   Above column1/(column1+column3) in percentage
6. Success rate of full backup
   Success rate of full backup means –
   Above column1/(column1+column2+ column3) in percentage
7. Percentage of backup coverage
   Percentage of backup coverage means –
   Above (column1+column3)/column4

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
RD = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/acharbha/Desktop/fullbackup_success/python/raw_Data_success_Rate.csv")
print(RD.info())
```

Comment: how can i upload  a sample raw data csv file.

Comment: you can't. maybe you can give some data in tabular format like the one discussed here. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41350/pandas-how-can-i-merge-two-dataframes?noredirect=1&lq=1